# Ruby / RSpec - Expect not to include any of

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following spec:

```
describe 'active' do
  it 'does not include inactive or deleted records' do
    inactive_record= create(:record, :inactive)
    deleted_record= create(:record, :deleted)
    expect(described_class.active).not_to include inactive_record
    expect(described_class.active).not_to include deleted_record
  end
end
```

This is OK when there are two tests, but when I have 10 different statuses I need to check, I'd need to write out ten different expect lines. I can do something like this:

```
[records_not_to_be_included].each { |record| expect(described_class.active).not_to include record }
```

But would like to be able to do something like:

```
expect(described_class.active).not_to include_any_of [records_not_to_be_included]
```

Is this possible with RSpec?

Comment: Would it be an option the test the opposite? That `described_class.active` only returns `active` items? Then it is just `expect(described_class.active).to all( be_active )`

Comment: That would cover this one, but I've found a few scenarios with more complicated logic where I may need to test a number are included and a number are not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, from the docs:

```
# Passes if actual includes expected. This works for
# collections and Strings. You can also pass in multiple args
# and it will only pass if all args are found in collection.
#
# @example
#   expect([1,2,3]).to      include(3)
#   expect([1,2,3]).to      include(2,3)
#   expect([1,2,3]).not_to  include(4)
#   expect("spread").to     include("read")
#   expect("spread").not_to include("red")
#   expect(:a => 1, :b => 2).to include(:b => 2, :a => 1)
#   expect(:a => 1, :b => 2).not_to include(:a => 2)
#   ...
def include(*expected)
  BuiltIn::Include.new(*expected)
end
```

`include` accepts one or more elements, so you can try with:

```
expect(described_class.active).not_to include(inactive_record, deleted_record)
```

Comment: But that makes me ask what's `active`? If that's specifically an enum which allows you to query the table by their value, then testing that wouldn't be neeed as you're testing the internals of Rails, which might be already covered.

Comment: I've got a few scenarios with more complicated logic where I need to explicitly check certain records don't get included - I didn't realise the above was possible, many thanks